# Use adb pull to copy app's file from phone (not rooted)

Tags: android, adb

I am using a MacBook as my development machine. My Android phone is not rooted. I want to copy my Android app's file from phone to my MacBook. I tried the following:

1. Connect Android phone to MacBook (Developer's option is enabled)
2. `adb pull /data/data/com.my.app/app_data/data ~/Documents/my/app/`

where `/data/data/com.my.app/app_data/data` is the file path on phone, and `~/Documents/my/app/` is the directory path on MacBook.

But the above `adb pull` command shows **Permission denied**.

I also tried to use `su` under `adb shell`, but it doesn't work either:

```
~$ adb shell
shell@xyz:/ $ su
/system/bin/sh: su: not found
```

So, how can I copy my app's internal file to my MacBook directory?

Answer (score 1):

You have to navigate to your file with `adb shell`.

Then copy to sdcard:

`cat yourfile > /sdcard/yourfile`

Then exit from adb shell and now you can pull:

`adb pull /sdcard/yourfile`

Comment: right! But do you have a typo that should be `cp` instead of `cat` ?

Comment: Maybe `cp` works too. I have done it always with `cat`. Just try it and tell me ;)

Comment: Anyway it will not work on a non-rooted phone because `/data/data/`is not accessible via adb (on current devices).

Comment: Try to use `run-as your.app.package` in adb shell instead of navigate to /data/data/whatever

Answer (score 1):

On a non-rooted phone you can not access the app private data directory (`/data/data/com.my.app`).

The only way to extract the data is to create a backup of the app data using `adb backupp`:

`adb backup -f mybackup.ab com.my.app`

For extracting the information from the created backup archive you can use the [Android Backup Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/). It converts the Android backup archive to a tar archive file.

Note: If the app specifies in it's manifest that backup is disallowed the described way does not work. In such a case the only way is to root the phone.